# Environment with optional argument configuration in TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht, arguments

I am tried to create configure the below environment with optional argument in TeX4ht

```
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\textit{#1}:\ \ignorespaces}
                            {}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][]{\def\arg{#1}\ifx\arg\empty\textit{Proof}\else\textit{#1}\fi:\ \ignorespaces}
                          {} 
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Sample text
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~1]
Sample text
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

CFG

```
\ConfigureEnv{proof}
         {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{<statement>\Hnewline\Hnewline<label>Proof</label>}\IgnoreIndent \ShowPar\par}
         {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{</statement>}}
         {}{}
```

I am using the optional argument in the definition, if the argument is present, it should be captured in the `<label>xxxxxx</label>` part, if else it should be
captured as like `<label>Proof</label>`

I am getting the wrong output

```
<statement>
<label>Proof</label>
<p class="noindent"><italic>Proof </italic>:&#x00A0;Sample text</p>
</statement>

<statement>
<label>Proof</label>
<p class="noindent"><italic>Proof of Theorem&#x00A0;1</italic>:&#x00A0;Sample text
</p></statement>
```

`Proof' was repeating due to the hard written in the in the`\ConfigureEnv`,

How to add the argument in the `\ConfigureEnv` ?

or how to get the expected result like below

```
<statement>
<label>Proof</label>
<p class="noindent">Sample text</p>
</statement>

<statement>
<label>Proof of Theorem&#x00A0;1</label>
<p class="noindent">Sample text</p>
</statement>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make move the proof  label printing part out of the environment to standalone command, which can be then configured to print your desired `<label>`:

package `myproof.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{myproof}

\newcommand\printproof[1]{\def\arg{#1}\ifx\arg\empty\textit{Proof}\else\textit{#1}\fi:}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][]{\printproof{#1}\ \ignorespaces}
                          {} 


\endinput
```

configuration file `myproof.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{printproof}{2}

\pend:defI\printproof{\a:printproof}
\append:defI\printproof{\b:printproof}

\ConfigureEnv{proof}
         {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{<statement>}\IgnoreIndent \ShowPar\par}
         {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{</statement>}}
         {}{}

\Configure{printproof}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<label>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</label>}\par}

\endinput
```

First, two hooks for tags inserting are defined using `\NewConfigure`, they are then inserted at the beginning and at the end of `\printproof` command using `\pend:defI` and `\append:defI` commands. The rest is just configuration for the tags. `\NoFonts` ... `\EndNoFonts` are used to suppress the italic fonts in `<label>` element.

The result:

```xml
<statement>
   <label>Proof :</label>
<!--l. 6--><p class="indent" >    Sample text
</p></statement>
   <statement>
   <label>Proof of Theorem 1:</label>
<!--l. 9--><p class="indent" >    Sample text
</p></statement>
```